# how can i switch one light bulb with two power source with relay?

Tags: arduino, ac, relay, inverter

I am making and project in which i take two inverters and connect with light source with the help of relay. I'm Planning to switch between two power sources with a Arduino like below diagram.So if one inverter fails then other will light up the bulb.

So i have came out with this circuit connection

IN1 & IN2 are inverters
[image]

Will this work.

Comment: I've seen more legible cave paintings to be honest.

Comment: Using an Arduino here is overkill.  You could do the same thing by just having IN1 power the relay and if it fails the relay opens and switches to IN2.

Comment: but can i use this configuration ?

Comment: I think I just squirted coffee out my nose... thank you @Andyaka....

Comment: @ElectronicGuy -- ok in principle yes.  I also found the schematic confusing at first. Obviously (or rather, not obviously) there is no description of what activates the relay, so must assume that will just work.

Comment: it will trigger by arduino

Comment: go for it. keep the arduino circuit isolated from this one, just in case there is any confusion with that ground.

Comment: ok i will try this

Comment: be careful. use inverters that don't blow up if something gets miswired

Comment: @ElectronicGuy - one more thing, and sorry if this is too basic for you. But I'll feel bad otherwise - make sure you get the relay working with a simpler/safer load first.